# Find neccessary and sufficient condition on $A,B,C,D$ in order that $M^{t}JM = J$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $I$ the $n \times n$ identity matrix over $\Bbb C$, and $J$ the $2n \times 2n$ matrix given by 
$$J = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & I \\
-I & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let $M$ be a $2n \times 2n$ matrix over $\Bbb C$ of the form:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are $n \times n$ matrices over $\Bbb C$. Find neccessary and sufficient conditions on $A,B,C,D$ in order that $M^{t}JM =J$

In the case $n=1$, we can easily prove that $M$ must have $\det M = 1$. So in this general case, I guess that the condition will be $\det(AD-BC) = 1$, but it seems more difficult. Suppose we have this bilinear form:

$$f((x_{1},x_{2},..., x_{2n}),(y_{1}, y_{2},...y_{2n})) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{n+i} - \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}x_{n+i}$$
Then $f$ has matrix in standard basis is $J$. So what we must do is to find all linear operator which preserves $f$. That means find all $T$ which satisfies $f(T\alpha, T\beta) = f(\alpha,\beta)$. What I guess is $f(T\alpha, T\beta) = \det (T)f(\alpha,\beta)$, but it's quite difficult for me. Anyone here can help me solve this problem using this approach. Thanks so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}M^tJM &= \left[\begin{array}{cc}A^t & C^t\\B^t & D^t\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & I\\-I & 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}A & B\\C & D\end{array}\right]\\ &= \left[\begin{array}{cc}-C^t & A^t\\-D^t & B^t\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}A & B\\C & D\end{array}\right]\\ &= \left[\begin{array}{cc}A^tC-C^tA & A^tD-C^tB\\B^tC-D^tA & B^tD-D^tB\end{array}\right]\\ &= \left[\begin{array}{cc}A^tC-(A^tC)^t & A^tD-C^tB\\-(A^tD-C^tB)^t & B^tD-(B^tD)^t\end{array}\right]\end{align}$$

Hence, it is necessary and sufficient that $A^tC$ and $B^tD$ are symmetric and that $A^tD-C^tB=I$. (Note that that last condition is equivalent to $\det M=1$ in the $n=1$ case, and that scalars--that is, $1\times 1$ matrices--are always symmetric.)

Comment: It's great. Thanks. But I think there's a more interesting way to prove this using the bilinear form :
 $$f((x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{2n}), (y_{1}, y_{2}, ..., y_{2n})) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}y_{n+i} - \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}x_{n+i}$$. We can easily see that this bilinear form have $J$ as matrix in standard basis. What we must do is to find the linear operator which preserve this bilinear form. That means find all $T$ in which $f(T\alpha, T\beta) = f(\alpha, \beta)$. I think we can prove that $f(T\alpha, T\beta) = \det (T)f(\alpha, \beta)$, but I can't prove it by myself. Do you got any clue?

Comment: I'm afraid my experience with bilinear forms is fairly limited. You don't have to accept my answer if it isn't quite what you're looking for. Someone else may come along and give a better one.

Comment: Yes, but your solution is still great. Thanks so much anyway. Hope someone can help me solve this problem using bilinear form :-)

Comment: You might want to add into your question that you're seeking a result using bilinear forms, and add the `(bilinear-form)` tag. You're more likely to get such an answer that way.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You're so kind. I've already done it :-D

Answer (score 3):

Note, if the matrix is defined over $\Bbb C$ you may (or may not) want the conjugate transpose..

Cameron has answered your question but it might be worth adding that as you have defined it $M$ is in the symplectic group $Sp(2n, \Bbb C)$ and it always satisfies $\det M=1$. To limit the possibilities to $\det M=\pm 1$ is easy enough:
$\det M^{t}JM=\det J$ 
$\det M^{t}\det J\det M= \left( \det M \right)^{2} \det J=\det J$ 
$\det M=\pm 1$ 
To prove $\det M \ne-1$ is a little more tricky but possible, see this review paper "On the determinant of symplectic matrices" by Mackey & Mackey http://homepages.wmich.edu/~mackey/detsymp.pdf

The symplectic group is the name for the group which preserves the nondegenerate, skew symmetric bilinear form; which is the bilinear form you have defined with $J$ in the standard basis.

To see why $M$ satisfies the symplectic matrix condition note that what you have written is equivalent to the standard way to write a skew-symmetric nondegenerate (i.e. symplectic) form, only you have expanded the matrix in components:
$f(x,y)=\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}y_{n+i} - \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}x_{n+i}=x^{t}Jy$.
Now take an arbitrary transformation acting on this form, i.e. a matrix $M$, and you have:
$f(Mx,My)=(Mx)^{t}J(My)=x^{t}M^{t}JMy$. 
Now demand $M$ preserves the symplectic form, i.e we want $f(Mx,My)=f(x,y)$, this implies:
$x^{t}M^{t}JMy=x^{t}Jy$ 
which is true for all $x,y$ iff:
$M^{t}JM=J$

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. But using bilinear form, $\det(M) = 1$ is just the neceessary condition, not sufficient. Is there anyway to find the sufficient condition using bilinear form? Do you have any hint for me? Thanks

Comment: Not sure I fully understand "show using bilinear form"? As I understand it, the sufficient condition is a restriction on the block matrices and best found using a matrix representation as Cameron showed.  If you're wondering how $M^{t}JM = J$ is required to preserve the form I could add that but I'm not sure that's what you're asking...

Comment: Ok, what I mean is that: Can we use bilinear form as an "indirect way" to solve this problem?For example, found condition such that $f(MX, MY) = f(X,Y)$, then that's the condition for $M^{t}JM = J$. But it seems unfeasible, right? Thanks so much for your help...

Comment: I have added a bit on the end of my answer, is that what you're asking? To me it seems that matrix notation is the simplest, but there may be another way to arrive at the same condition that I'm not aware of...

Comment: Yes, that's what I wannna ask and expect. Thanks so much for your consideration...